# Select carrier to transport pallet from Europe to USA

Tags: usa, budget, shipping, central-europe

I'm planning to move from Switzerland to the US for about 2 years and plan to bring along about 2 pallet of stuff with me, next to the baggage I can bring along in the plain.

I personally don't mind when this extra gear takes a month or two to arrive. So time-wise this would be fine. Of course I'm looking for a cost optimized solution as long as my packages do not get damaged (humidity,... - not especially fragile).

Now I heard via ship might be the best. Since I never did this my question what criteria should I use when selecting the carrier.

Comment: This question is likely more suited to be asked on [expatriates.SX](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com) - you might also try searching for similar questions there.

Comment: Sure, the solution is Kuehne & Nagel. They do the best job, they are the most "everywhere", and generally the price is the most reasonable - it's hardly worth getting other quotes.  kn-portal.com and choose CH.  Regarding the question "ship or plane etc?" - just forget it, don't worry about it. Your friendly KN person will figure out what's best, it's all they do all day

Comment: @JoeBlow. I did call them but they told me they don't deal with private persons - but they forewarded me to a good company who does this kind of stuff. So thanks for your help

Comment: Hey Magu - that's totally weird!  Thank you so much for that information.  I guess K+N in switzerland in particular do not deal w private persons, then. In other euro. countries they do -- well, that is GREAT informationm thank you!  Glad you found a solution. I guess whoever they put you on to, will in fact, use them as the shipper. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for **freight-forwarders** locally.
They will combine your stuff (boxed and labeled) in a container with any other house moves heading in the same direction. Depending on the popularity of the destination it can take a few weeks for a container to fill. It then takes 10-14 days to ship to the USA and a few days to reach the city at the other side (depending how far inland you are)

If you deliver boxes to their local depot in your city and collect from the port/depot at the other end it will only cost a few $/kg by sea.  They will also collect from your place and deliver to your destination address for more $$$.

They handle all the paperwork, customs etc.